# MkMapView setRegion animation prevents touch events on Annotation Views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, mkmapview

We have a MKmapView with a bunch of Image Annotation where each Image annotation responds to touch
by overriding these methods of AnnotationView subclass:

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

     -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Our map region is updated using

```
[MkMapView setRegion:animated:]
```

whenever the new location is received and is far enough from the old location to make a difference.

What I noticed is that if we set **animated** flag to **YES** the touches on our annotation are rarely detected(probably due to the fact that main thread is busy animating between two map regions.
When we set **animated** flag to **NO**, everything is fine, but map transition may(or may not) become jerky.

The question I have is whether this is an expected behavior of **animated** flag of [MkMapView setRegion:animated] function or whether there is a workaround for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the mapview being animated has its userInteractionEnabled property set to no during the animation.  If you need to change this behavior, you should subclass the view and override the appropriate methods.

Alternatively, you could place a transparent view over the mapview for the duration of the animation to capture specific types of actions, such as respond to a double-tap to stop the change in region.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on userInteractionEnabled property changes, i couldnt find any info on why and when the system may decide to change this property though. However, i could potentially listen to its changes via KVO and switch it back when neccessary.

Comment: However, our app has a navigation toolbar with buttons above mkMapView. 
And the problem is, during the setRegion animations not only annotationviews are unresponsive to touches, but also the buttons on the toolbar. If [MkMapView setRegion:region animated:YES] blocks the main thread, it only makes sense that the buttons are non-responsive.

Comment: @VladimirGurovich How did this answer solve your problem? I observe the userInteractionEnabled property and there is no change there.

Comment: @vrwim Since my comment is now 7 years old and refers to the version IOS SDK that is several major version bumps behind, i dont know if this answer is relevant, but honestly i just dont remember.